# array of struct pointers

Tags: c

I'm basically trying to create an array of struct pointers. Each of these pointers is supposed to point to another element of the same structure array i.e BLOCKS[2].

This is what I've done so far.

```
typedef struct bb {
      ..
      ..
      ..
    struct bb **successor;
} BLOCK;

BLOCK BLOCKS[10];

struct bb **A = malloc(sizeof(struct bb*)*5);        //create an array of pointers of type struct bb, 5 units i.e A[0]->A[4]. 

BLOCKS[0].successors = A                            //just assigning
```

Now......how do I assign the first element of the pointer array, A, to another structure?

I tried:

```
A[0] = &BLOCKS[6];
```

It compiles fine but I get a seg fault.

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a debugger?

Comment: Where does it seg fault?

Comment: It seg faults at "A[0] = &BLOCKS[6];".

Comment: Your code runs fine on my system. The error is probably somewhere else in your program. What other members does struct bb have? What other things do you do with it? Unless malloc fails to allocate memory, there is no reason why that assignment should fail.

Comment: Well it's definitely that line that causes the segfault. I have two other members of type unsigned int. But I might add that in my code that line is in a loop, does that matter??

Comment: On which platform u r running it??

Comment: @maxflow Could you add the loop to your question, as well as any other code that runs in connection with the assignment?

Comment: Using xcode.
@jforberg, not sure if I can do that it's quite long. Can i email you? :)

Comment: maxflow, I think it would go against the spirit of this community if you sent me code privately. Also, I'm no C expert and there's no guarantee I could solve your problem on my own. Perhaps you could include as much as you think may be relevant in connection with *the assignment* here in the question, keeping it down to a reasonable amount?

Comment: @jforberg I fixed it. The loops were the issue. It seems that you can only use **A if it is created in the SAME loop, I tried to access it in a nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one:

```
typedef struct bb {
      ..
      ..
      ..
    struct bb *successor;
} BLOCK;

BLOCK BLOCKS[10];

struct bb *A = malloc(sizeof(struct bb)*5);        //create an array of pointers of
type struct bb, 5 units i.e A[0]->A[4]. 

BLOCKS[0].successors = A[0];
```

Because after looking at it quickly I think the ** should render into * and your malloc is reserving memory not for the size of 5 structures but the size of 5 pointers to this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Question: *"**I'm basically trying to create an array of struct pointers.**"*

The array of structure pointer should be

```
BLOCK *ptrBlockArr[10]; //This an array of size 10, which can store 10 pointers to the structure BLOCK
```

Now, since, these are pointers, you will have allocated memory for each of the elements. This should be done like

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   ptrBlockArr[i] = (BLOCK *)malloc(sizeof(BLOCK));
}
```

You question also included: *"**Each of these pointers is supposed to point to another element of the same structure array**"* . This can be done like

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++) // Run the loop till the last but one element
{
  ptrBlockArr[i]->successor = ptrBlockArr[i+1];
}
//Assign the last's element's sucessor as the first element. This will make it circular. Check if this is your intention
ptrBlockArr[9]->successor = ptrBlockArr[0]
```

Please note that in your structure `successor` is `struct bb**`, whereas it should be `struct bb*`.

Also, you can optimize the code to combine the two loops shown by me above into one loop. I'll leave that to you to learn by yourself and implement.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't follow the structure of my code. i'm trying to create an array of struct pointers that is also a member of each structure.